# Desktop PC with one HDMI and one VGA port

Tags: hdmi, conversion, vga

I am considering purchasing a Desktop PC, that has one HDMI port and one VGA port. [image: HDMI VGA port] I have two monitors, both of them support HDMI. Will I be able to purchase VGA (Male) to HDMI converter and use it with my monitor

Comment: Passive HDMI (Source) to VGA (Display) is possible the reverse isn’t. Active VGA to HDMI adapters do exist

Comment: @Ramhound - what does that mean? if the Machine has HDMI it can be connected to VGA monitor with an adapter, but if Machine has VGA, it can't be connected to HDMI monitors ?

Comment: What do you mean, “what does it mean”, HDMI is digital and VGA is analog. You cannot convert analog to a digital signal without an active adapter. My original comment is perfectly clear

Comment: And you would also need an active converter for digital to analog. There are no "*passive HDMI to VGA adapters*" that work.  Any sort of HDMI signal to VGA signal connection in either direction requires an active converter.  The converter might be powered by its source connector, and not require an external power source, but that does not make it "*passive*".  But there are HDMI ports have have both HDMI and VGA signals.

Comment: "*Will I be able to purchase VGA (Male) to HDMI converter and use it with my monitor*" -- Such converters do exist.

Comment: Have you checked it is even capable of using both those outputs simultaneously? That looks like the most absolute basic mobo, possibly a design from ten years ago or more [no-one is going to put VGA on a modern board]. I'm sure you could find something that would serve you better straight out of the box, rather than that.

Comment: A converter will fit this.

Comment: @BlockchainOffice - sure it will, but at the pre-purchase stage it might just be simpler/cheaper to buy what you actually need in the first place, rather than kludge it up afterwards.

Comment: Looks like a mini tower, you can't put in a second graphic card with 2/3/4 hdmi outputs?

Comment: @sawdust - I consider an adapter that doesn’t require USB power to be passive l should have clarified my statement (and paid attention to the product I found)

Comment: I said I should have clarified my comment, absolutely no need to be rude, I am aware my comment wasn’t 100% clear